# get value from address bar using url rewriting

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess, url-rewriting

i am using .htaccess file to user url rewriting and it's working properly. when i user this for an user then i write

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule   ^user/([0-9]+)/?$   index.php?user=$1  [NCL]
```

and it's working
but when i use this for pagination..it's not working.

```
RewriteRule   ^user/([0-9]+)/page/([0-9]+)?$   index.php?user=$1&page=$1  [NCL]
```

page successfully open but when i get value of page no then it return only user id in both condition with get user id and page no.

Comment: Can you debug with a print_r($_GET) ? And change the name of the file (index.php -> index2.php) to see which rule is working ?

Comment: Shouldn't be `&page=$2` ?

Comment: thnx  @DamienPirsy it's working now..

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
RewriteRule   ^user/([0-9]+)/page/([0-9]+)?$   index.php?user=$1&page=$2  [NCL]

                     ^ $1          ^ $2
```

each part encapsulated in braces results in a new variable